# How do I force the browser to only handle the top link if 2 elements are clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

Say I have the following code:

```
<div onclick='location.href="http://www.example.com/"'>
  <a href='#' onclick='alert("blah")'>click</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to only have the anchor evaluated when I click the 'click' text and not have the div's onclick evaluated?

Comment: I'm sure there are better and more simple alternatives that you could be using rather than putting onClick events inside elements that also have onClick events. If you really need this function, you really should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stop event propagation by returning `false` from the anchor's click event handler.

```
<div onclick='location.href="http://www.example.com/"'>
  <a href='#' onclick='alert("blah"); return false;'>click</a>
</div>
```

You've tagged this question with jQuery. In that case, you should be using unobtrusive Javascript so:

```
<div id="someid">
  <a href="#">click</a>
</div>
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#someid").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
  });
  $("#someid a").click(function() {
    alert("blah");
    return false;
  });
});
```

is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: return false won't stop event propagation, it will only cancel the href link. (Regarding regular JS; I'm not familiar with jQuery)

Comment: It wouldn't work with jQuery either. Returning false only stops execution for that specific element, it doesn't affect any other elements which might also have events. It's just like returning false in a function. It doesn't stop executing the entire page just because one function returned false, it just stops that function.

Comment: cletus is close.  Add an event parameter to the click handler function and call event.preventDefault() in the function body to prevent the default functionality of the element.

Comment: Actually `return false` stops propagation (and prevents default).

Comment: @komforce try it. `return false` absolutely stops event propagation. Try commenting out `return false` and seeing the difference.

Comment: @cletus: That was the first thing I tried. Returning false does NOT prevent the onClick event on the div from executing. (Tested in Firefox and IE.)

Comment: @animuson you have some other problem. I've tried it on Chrome and FF and it prevents it fine. Are you sure you're not clicking on the div and not the anchor? Believe me it works and this is intended behaviour. Look for some other problem.

Comment: Ah, nice! My apologies though--I realized this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180211/jquery-div-click-with-anchors

But your answer is absolutely right! I've changed my jQuery accordingly.

Comment: @cletus: Plain JS will not cancel the propagation in this example with a return false. I've even tried the code verbatim, and it alerts the box (proof the `a` tag was clicked) and then goes to the website after pressing `OK`. I've never seen the behavior as you describe it, and would be interested in seeing a live demonstration.

Comment: @cletus, @konforce, you're both right. `return false` will stop the default action plus it will stop bubbling, but only in jQuery. Sans-jQuery, `return false` does not stop propagation of the event, it only stops the default action.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.

```
<div onclick='location.href="http://www.example.com/"'>
  <a href='#' onclick='alert("blah"); event.cancelBubble = true; if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); return false;'>click</a>
</div>
```

- `event.cancelBubble` is for IE
- `event.stopPropagation()` is W3C
- return false is to cancel the href link.