# Clickable LI overrules links within the LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a LI with some information, including some links. I would like jQuery to make the LI clickable, but also remain the links in the LI.

The Clickable part works. I just need the links within to work as well.
*NOTE: They work if you right click and choose "Open in new tab".*

**HTML**

```
<ul id="onskeliste">
    <li url="http://www.dr.dk">Some info with links <a href="http://www.imerco.dk" target="_blank">Imerco</a></a>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#onskeliste li").click(
 function()
 {
  window.location = $(this).attr("url");
  return false;
 });

})(jQuery);
```

I've found a simular question here, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.
[jQuery DIV click, with anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180211/jquery-div-click-with-anchors)

Can you help me?? :-)

Thank you in advance...

Comment: This is bad practice and not progressively enhancing a webpage, just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your having is caused by [event propagation](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).
The click on the <a/> tag bubbles up to the <li/> tag, therefore causing the li's `click` event to "overrule" the link's click.

Essentially, the li's click happens *immediately* after the clicking on the link. It's like you've clicked on a link to one site, and then clicked a link to a different site before the browser had a chance to change the page.
A solution to this would be to stop the event from bubbling up to the <li/>, thus preventing it from changing the window's location.

I suggest using `event.stopPropagation()` on the <a/> tag, like this:

```
$('#onskeliste li a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm, and with the least amout of code - therefor this is the solution I accept... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the event target, like:

```
$("#onskeliste li").bind('click', function(e){
   switch(e.target.nodeName){
       case 'LI':{
           e.preventDefault();
           e.stopPropagation();
           window.location = $(e.target).attr('url');
           break;
       }
       case 'A':{
           // do something               
           break;
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I can't get it to work Andy. What does the "case 'div':{" do? Should I put "window.location = $(this).attr("url");" where you wrote "Do something"? 

Can you insert my information as above, to illustrate your idea better?

Comment: I actually already did that. You can remove the 'DIV' part, it was just an example that 'nodeName' can contain any DOM element. The interesting part for you is the 'A' closure. Should do the work.

Comment: Doh, I actually didn't understand in the first place. I edited the code which should do the trick now. But beware, using custom attribute tags might cause some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just change the mark up to this and not write js for this?

```
<ul id="onskeliste">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.dr.dk">Some info with links</a>
        <a href="http://www.imerco.dk" target="_blank">Imerco</a></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GeReV said, it's event propagation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#onskeliste li').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(':not(a)')) {
      window.location = $(this).attr('url');
      return false;
    }
  });
 })(jQuery);
```

This looks at what you clicked and if it's not a link it looks at the `url` attribute on the list element. If it is a link it does its normal link thing.